# Parse Dynamic Property name in Azure Logic App

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have been playing around with Azure Logic Apps and trying to retrieve a Pocket (ReadItLater) article so that I can create a new task in my preferred Task Manager. I have Two HTTP Connectors (one for Retrieve Operation using Pocket API and another post data to Todoist (my preferred task manager).

I can retrieve the Article and the response looks like (removed a few properties below for easy reading):

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "status": "200 OK"
    },
    "body": {
        "status": 1,
        "complete": 1,
        "list": {
            "586327616": {
                "item_id": "586327616",
                "resolved_id": "586327616",
                "given_url": "http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/?utm_source=hackernewsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_term=design&mc_cid=58c9499fa2&mc_eid=3aaf6c4e47",
                "given_title": "slick - the last carousel you'll ever need",
                "time_added": "1396652224",
                "time_updated": "1405156517",
                "resolved_title": "slick",
                "resolved_url": "http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/?utm_source=hackernewsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_term=design&mc_cid=58c9499fa2&mc_eid=3aaf6c4e47",
                "excerpt": "Add slick.js before your closing <body> tag, after jQuery (requires jQuery 1.7 +) <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"slick/slick.min.",
                "word_count": "22"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to parse the above response to retrieve individual article properties (i.e. resolved_title). The issue here is the object under the list "586327616" is dynamic and changes for every article, and I can't seem to parse this as an expression in Logic App. My current action in Logic App looks like:

```
    "postToTodoist": {
        "conditions": [
            {
                "expression": "@equals(outputs('getPocketArticles')['statusCode'], 200)"
            },
            {
                "dependsOn": "getPocketArticles"
            }
        ],
        "inputs": {
            "body": "@{outputs('getPocketArticles')['body']['list'][0]['resolved_title']}",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            "method": "POST",
            "repeat": {},
            "uri": "https://todoist.com/API/v6/add_item"
        },
        "type": "Http"
    }
```

For the expression I have tried converting the response to string, using coalesce and trying to access using an index, but nothing seem to work. In the error, it tells me what that the available property is i.e.:

```
{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Unable to process template language expressions in action 'postToTodoist' inputs at line '1' and column '11': 'The template language expression 'coalesce(body('getPocketArticles')['list']).resolved_title' cannot be evaluated because property 'resolved_title' doesn't exist, available properties are '586327616'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'."}
```

I feel that it is not possible to construct an expression without knowing the name of the property, has anyone done something similar?

Comment: try this outputs('getPocketArticles')['body']['list']['resolved_title']. From your output response it does not seems like "list" is not array.

Comment: I have tried that, and I get the same error like before: {"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Unable to process template language expressions in action 'postToTodoist' inputs at line '1' and column '11': 'The template language expression 'outputs('getPocketArticles')['body']['list']['resolved_title']' cannot be evaluated because property 'resolved_title' doesn't exist, available properties are '579786093'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'."}

Comment: Correct, today it is only possible to select a particular property by its name. There is no support for iterating over json object properties the way you would iterate over an array. Feel free to submit a feature request via https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps