# How can I get the string value of the name of a property in a dynamic type in Azure Log Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have a value of type `dynamic`, the JSON representation of which looks like:

`{ "ReportName": { "Duration": 2347, "RowCount": 1167 } }`

I would like to extract the string value "ReportName" from this, as I have many rows with a similar structure, but the name of the "root" property can differ for each one.

This seems like it should be easy, but I am struggling. I have arrived at this juncture by doing an `mvexpand` on a sub-property of a much larger JSON value/entity further up in my query, which has a variety of different property names inside it.

I have tried casting this to a string (using `tostring()`) and using `jsonextract("$", value)`, plus several similar variants, but none of them seem to work (I get NULLs back).

Thanks!

Comment: Possible dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039961/parse-dynamic-property-name-in-azure-logic-app

Comment: I managed to work around this by using a regex `extract()` call on the `tostring()`-casted value. Would still be nice to have a feature that would allow you to iterate/inspect arbitrary JSON/dynamic properties in ALA.